# Run cmd.exe as a admin to install the software's using c#

Tags: winui, winui-3

**Technologies Used**

**Langauage : C#**

**Scripting : cmd.exe and commands**

**Front End : WIN UI, Xaml**

**Framework : .Net 5**

- I want to install bunch of 10 software's as a automated process from
  c#.
- Currently To install software I am using cmd.exe as a Process using C# Process class and
  this should be run as admin or else my installation will get failed
  due to the admin privilege's.
- Problem here is When my automation starts, system is always
  asking me UAC(User Account Control) pop up to install the every software(I want skip UAC pop
  always).

**Query** : How to avoid this UAC pop when I use cmd.exe as admin from C# process classes.

**Proposed solution from others:** On my application(WIN UI) launch, create a singleton process with elevate the cmd.exe/powershell.exe as admin and use this process to install all the software's.(in this case we will get one time UAC pop up and this is ok). So I can call this process/service to execute all my commands to avoid the UAC pop up as this process is running as admin

**Approaches Tried for the Proposed solution :**

1. Followed this article https://code-ai.mk/execute-command-prompt-commands-from-c/ .

```
public class CmdService : IDisposable
  {
      private Process _cmdProcess;
      private StreamWriter _streamWriter;
      private AutoResetEvent _outputWaitHandle;
      private string _cmdOutput;

      public CmdService(string cmdPath)
      {
          _cmdProcess = new Process();
          _outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
          _cmdOutput = String.Empty;

          ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
          processStartInfo.FileName = cmdPath;
          processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
          processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
          processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
          processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
          processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;           

          _cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += _cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;

          _cmdProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
          _cmdProcess.Start();

          _streamWriter = _cmdProcess.StandardInput;
          _cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
      }

      public string ExecuteCommand(string command)
      {
          _cmdOutput = String.Empty;

          _streamWriter.WriteLine(command);
          _streamWriter.WriteLine("echo end");
          _outputWaitHandle.WaitOne();
          return _cmdOutput;
      }

      private void _cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Data == null || e.Data == "end")
              _outputWaitHandle.Set();
          else
              _cmdOutput += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          _cmdProcess.Close();
          _cmdProcess.Dispose();
          _streamWriter.Close();
          _streamWriter.Dispose();
      }
  }
}
```

- In this approach cmd.exe process is not running as admin due to the useShellExecute set to false.
- If you set useShellExecute to false Process is running under non admin mode , so my software
  installation is failed.

**Query** : how I can run cmd.exe as admin in this case

2. **Approach 2** : Created a process to open cmd.exe as an admin by setting the useShellExecute = true;

   ```
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                     startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                   startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                   startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                   startInfo.Arguments = @"msiexec.exe /qn /norestart /i C:\Temp\somesoftware.msi INSTALLDIR=c:\tep\somesoftware  ALLUSERS=1 REBOOT=ReallySupress /log C:\Logs\somesoftwarelog.txt";
                   var pro = new Process();
                   pro.StartInfo = startInfo;
                   pro.Start();
   ```

**Issues :** In this approach I am not able to execute the commands via standardinputs due to the UseShellExecute property to true. As there is restriction if you use UseShellExecute to true we cannot redirect the standard input/output to the process.

**Query** : How I can provide inputs commands to cmd.exe when UseShellExecute  to true

**Note : I cannot run my WIN UI application as admin due to the issues in WIN UI(https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3046).**

Comment: You understand the **point** of UAC is to **stop** random apps from running other programs as administrator, right?    That is, you are fighting against the system.

Comment: Yes, Agreed with your point. But there are some cases when there is no user intervention   like automated process system should allow . In my case how I can achieve my requirement ?

Comment: The way to do it is to run your top-level program elevated.  Why can't you do that?  I don't know what "due to the issues" means.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But we are using WIN UI 3 and it is in preview mode and this is know issue. We would need alternate ways to over come this one. As there is no update on this issue https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3046

Comment: Is it resolved. I am also facing same issue.